# Fuzzy Matching: avoiding "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r

I understand that "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" is caused by passing $ to the wrong kind of object: an atomic one instead of a recursive one.

However, I get it when I run a code chunk that works for other people. I'm trying to find what I'm doing wrong or an alternative solution.

I have two data frames:

```
> str(DF1)
'data.frame':   5977 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ coolThings: chr  "Surfing" "wearing sunglasses" "being an honest person" ...

> str(DF2)
'data.frame':   2999 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ coolThings: chr  "Surf" "Sun glasses" "being honest" ...
```

My goal is to create a third data frame that matches the most similar strings of DF1 and DF2. To do so I am following [this article on fuzzy matching](http://bigdata-doctor.com/fuzzy-string-matching-survival-skill-tackle-unstructured-information-r/#comment-942).

The first part of the code works fine for me:

```
# It creates a matrix with the Standard Levenshtein distance between the name fields of both sources
dist.coolthings <- adist(DF1$coolThings, DF2$coolThings, partial = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)

# We now take the pairs with the minimum distance
min.coolthings <- apply(dist.coolthings , 1, min)
```

However, when I get to the for loop...

```
match.c1.c2 <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(dist.coolthings))
{
    c2.i <- match(min.coolthings[i],dist.coolthings[i,])
    c1.i <- i
    match.c1.c2<-rbind(data.frame(c2.i=c2.i,c1.i=c1.i,c2coolthings =DF2[c2.i,]$coolThings, c1coolthings=DF1[c1.i,]$coolThings, adist=min.coolthings[i]), match.c1.c2)
}
```

...I get the mentioned error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

DF1[c1.i,] and DF2[c2.i,] are indeed atomic:

```
> is.atomic(DF1[c1.i,])
[1] TRUE
```

So it make sense that I get this error, but... How to avoid it?

I am using someone else's code and I am not familiar with some of the expressions it uses, maybe someone with more experience does an can give me a hand.

Thanks in advance,

Guillem

Comment: Rather than `DF2[c2.i,]$coolThings`, try `DF2[c2.i, "coolThings"]`. Same thing for `DF1`. Alternatively you can likely do: `DF2[c2.i, , drop = FALSE]$coolThings`. The issue is because your `data.frame`s only have one column so when you subset it will return a vector. To make it return a `data.frame` you need the `drop = FALSE`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very very much, @MikeH. It also makes perfect sense the explanation. Cheers :-)

Comment: No problem. I posted my comment as answer for future readers and to mark this as "complete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into issues because `DF1` and `DF2` are both single column `data.frame`s. When you subset a single column `data.frame` it drops the `data.frame` class and returns a vector. Thus using `$` won't work. To get around this you can do either:

1. Select the specific column you want in the subsetting. For your code for `DF2` this would be `DF2[c2.1, "coolThings"]`.

or

2. Use `drop = FALSE` to make sure your subsetting doesn't return a vector. For `DF2` this would look like `DF2[c2.1, , drop = FALSE]$coolThings`.

I personally prefer method 1, but both should work.